# How to show div on input focus in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a input and a div whose height and width is equal to border bottom of input. I just want to show div which is firstly hidden.

```css
.cool{
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  outline: none;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;
  border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}
div.bar{
  width: 365.3px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #42c0fb;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  display: none;
}
input:focus .bar{
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div style = "margin: auto;">
  <input class = "cool" type = "text" />
  <div class = "bar"></div>
</div>
```

Please help. The above code doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `input:focus  .bar` selector, the browser searches for `.bar` under the descendents of `input`. Whereas, `.bar` is a sibling of the `input`.

You could use one of the sibling selectors here. Like: `input:focus + .bar` or `input:focus ~ .bar`

```css
.cool {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  outline: none;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;
  border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}

div.bar {
  width: 365.3px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #42c0fb;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  display: none;
}

input:focus + .bar {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: auto;">
  <input class="cool" type="text" />
  <div class="bar"> Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```css
/* form starting stylings ------------------------------- */
.group      { 
  position:relative; 
  margin-bottom:45px; 
}
input     {
  font-size:18px;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
}
input:focus   { outline:none; }



/* active state */
input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label   {
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#5264AE;
}

/* BOTTOM BARS ================================= */
.bar  { position:relative; display:block; width:300px; }
.bar:before, .bar:after  {
  content:'';
  height:2px; 
  width:0;
  bottom:1px; 
  position:absolute;
  background:#42c0fb; 
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}
.bar:before {
  left:50%;
}
.bar:after {
  right:50%; 
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ .bar:before, input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width:50%;
}

/* HIGHLIGHTER ================================== */
.highlight {
  position:absolute;
  height:60%; 
  width:100px; 
  top:25%; 
  left:0;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:0.5;
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ .highlight {
  -webkit-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}

/* ANIMATIONS ================ */
@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
@-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
@keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
```

```html
<div class="group">      
      <input type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
     
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sibling selector `+` for this. check updated snippet below..

```css
.cool{
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  outline: none;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;
  border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}
div.bar{
  width: 365.3px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #42c0fb;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  display: none;
}
input:focus + .bar{
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div style = "margin: auto;">    
    <input class = "cool" type = "text" />
    <div class = "bar">bar text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The sibling selector will work for you in this case.

But you could also use [:focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

```css
.cool {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  outline: none;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;
  border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}

div.bar {
  width: 365.3px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #42c0fb;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  display: none;
}

div:focus-within .bar {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: auto;">
  <input class="cool" type="text" />
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  .cool{
   font-size: 30px;
   margin: auto;
   outline: none;
   padding-bottom: 0.2em;
   border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
   border-bottom-color: black;
    }
  div.bar{
     width: 365.3px;
     height: 2px;
     background-color: #42c0fb;
     position: relative;
     top: -2px;
     display: none;
        }
  input:focus + .bar{
   display: block
      }
```

```html
<div style = "margin: auto;">
  <input class = "cool" type = "text" />
  <div class = "bar"></div>
</div>
```